# Center UL table inside DIV

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I can't center a UL block inside a div, with a fixed width. The CSS I have is this:

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    display: table;margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    list-style: none;
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #006;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

The UL is a little bit too far to the right

Comment: could you post html markup as well?

Comment: It looks centered to me: http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/h96jd/

Comment: Why do you have `min-width` and `max-width` when you already have a fixed width of `960px` set?

Comment: But post your HTML, or better yet, use my existing JSFiddle^^, and modify it